# How to place svg inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I try to create multiple svg tag inside of the div, I want all the svg exist only inside of the parent div tag, if the coordinate of the svg is larger than the size of the div, I want the div become a scroll bar to expand the space. I also want to place the svg in the position I want. I am not sure how to make it happen? Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testbtm').click(function() {
    var svgElement = $('<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content">\
            <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
            <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>');
    svgElement.children('text').text(1);
    svgElement.attr("class", "hexagon ui-widget-content");
    $("#display").append(svgElement);
    svgElement.click(hexagonClick);
  }); //end click
  $('#testbtm2').click(function() {
    $('.hexagon').each(function() {
      var svgElement = $('<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-  content">\
            <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
            <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>');
      svgElement.children('text').text(1);
      svgElement.attr("class", "hexagon ui-widget-content");
      $("#display").append(svgElement);
      svgElement.click(hexagonClick);
    });
  }); // end click
  $('.hexagon').click(hexagonClick); // end click
}); // end ready
```

```css
#display {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display">
</div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
<button id="testbtm2">test2</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overflow: auto;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testbtm').click(function() {
    var svgElement = $('<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content">\
            <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
            <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>');
    svgElement.children('text').text(1);
    svgElement.attr("class", "hexagon ui-widget-content");
    $("#display").append(svgElement);
    svgElement.click(hexagonClick);
  }); //end click
  $('#testbtm2').click(function() {
    $('.hexagon').each(function() {
      var svgElement = $('<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-  content">\
            <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
            <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>');
      svgElement.children('text').text(1);
      svgElement.attr("class", "hexagon ui-widget-content");
      $("#display").append(svgElement);
      svgElement.click(hexagonClick);
    });
  }); // end click
  $('.hexagon').click(hexagonClick); // end click
}); // end ready
```

```css
#display {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="display">
</div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
<button id="testbtm2">test2</button>
```

Comment: Hi, what about I want to place the svg in the coordinate that I want, I only know how to place a svg, and the position is automatically placed, but how do I place the svg such as x = 300, y = 400? Thank you

Comment: You should try with css properties: `position: relative; top: 20px; left: 10px;`. These properties must be implemented in the `<svg>` tag.